# Codeigniter get_file_info() returns filename as false

Tags: php, file, codeigniter, directory

I am building a Codeigniter based File Browser but having a problem with file information.

I have loaded helpers:

```
$this->load->helper('file');
$this->load->helper('directory');
```

When I called `var_dump(get_file_info('gui/default/uploads/profile_200x200.jpg'));` here is the result: (note that path is relative to `site_url()`)

```
array (size=4)
  'name' => boolean false
  'server_path' => string 'gui/default/uploads/subfold/profile_200x200.jpg' (length=47)
  'size' => int 9714
  'date' => int 1386054354
```

But when I called `get_filenames()` or `get_dir_file_info()` from very same built-in file helper it displays filenames correctly. Any experience or idea what causes this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

due to bug with this function (read from [here](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/134247/))
use this workaround:

```
$file = 'gui/default/uploads/profile_200x200.jpg';
$fileinfo = get_file_info($file);
if(!$fileinfo['name']) $fileinfo['name'] = basename($file);
```

Comment: thank you for the link and the solution. I've chosen the modify the core and take a note for Core FIX. Thanks.